# Partial String map from pandas dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a mapping dictionary written this way.
How can I do a partial string search for the same?
For e.g even if its `East South Central Division Conv` in text I need to map to 1,21,28,47 states.
Also I need to match irrerspective of case ans spaces.

`state_code` is a column I have in `df` with the numbers like 9,23,25,33

```
dct.update(dict.fromkeys([34,36,42],'Middle Atlantic'))
dct.update(dict.fromkeys([18,17,26,39,55],'East North Central'))
dct.update(dict.fromkeys([19,20,27,29,31,38,46],'West North Central'))
dct.update(dict.fromkeys([10,11,12,13,24,37,45,51,54],'South Atlantic'))
dct.update(dict.fromkeys([1,21,28,47],'East South Central'))
dct.update(dict.fromkeys([5,22,40,48],'West South Central'))
dct.update(dict.fromkeys([4,8,16,35,30,49,32,56],'Mountain'))
dct.update(dict.fromkeys([2,6,15,41,53],'Pacific'))
dct.update(dict.fromkeys([0],'Other'))

df['MAPPING'] = df['state_code'].map(dct)
```

Comment: I don't understand wht the the number is the key and the strings the value if you want to replace text by number? Can you update your question with the output of `print(df['state_code'].head())`, please?

Comment: updated nformation

Comment: So why it's important to match partial string? I don't understand what your have as input and what you want as output. Please provide a real example.